# Disable click button until opened tab is closed

Tags: html, css

I am making a manual in which requires users to fill in a survey (from other site) and I don't want the "Finish The Survey" button to be clickable until the survey is done (or the tab is closed).
Since I cannot change the source code of told other site, is there a possible way to accomplish this requirement?

Comment: Probably not.... Does the 3rd party site give you info it is completed?

Comment: I don' think so. Api is not an option in this situation.